# Java Code not printing Keys and Values of HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, subclass, superclass

My code inputs a user-defined string and categorizes it as DNA, RNA, or ODD. The output is supposed to print the keys and values of the HashMap **nucleotide_hmap** but the code currently does not. What should I change in my code so that it works?

Here is what the code should output:
(if user inputs sequence ATGC)

- ATGC
- A   1 : 0.25
- T   1 : 0.25
- C   1 : 0.25
- G   1 : 0.25
- Sequence Length: 4
- Reverse sequence: CGTA
- Reverse complement: GCAT

And this is one of my subclasses:

```
package sequenceclasses; 

public class DNASequence extends MainSequence {
    public DNASequence(String dna_sequence){
        the_sequence = dna_sequence; 
        complement_hmap.put('A', 'T');
        complement_hmap.put('T', 'A');
        complement_hmap.put('C', 'G');
        complement_hmap.put('G', 'C');
    }   
    public void nuc_content(String dna_sequence){
        the_sequence = dna_sequence;
        double[] counts_ratios = new double[8];
        for (int i = 0; i < dna_sequence.length(); i++){
            if (dna_sequence.charAt(i) == 'A'){
                counts_ratios[0] += 1;}
            if (dna_sequence.charAt(i) == 'T'){
                counts_ratios[1] += 1;}
            if (dna_sequence.charAt(i) == 'C'){
                counts_ratios[2] += 1;}
            if (dna_sequence.charAt(i) == 'G'){
                counts_ratios[3] += 1;}
            }
            if (dna_sequence.length() > 0){
                counts_ratios[4] = counts_ratios[0] / dna_sequence.length();
                counts_ratios[5] = counts_ratios[1] / dna_sequence.length();
                counts_ratios[6] = counts_ratios[2] / dna_sequence.length();
                counts_ratios[7] = counts_ratios[3] / dna_sequence.length();
        }       
        String A_content = Double.toString(counts_ratios[0]) + " , " + Double.toString(counts_ratios[4]);
        String T_content = Double.toString(counts_ratios[1]) + " , " + Double.toString(counts_ratios[5]); 
        String C_content = Double.toString(counts_ratios[2]) + " , " + Double.toString(counts_ratios[6]);
        String G_content = Double.toString(counts_ratios[3]) + " , " + Double.toString(counts_ratios[7]);

        nucleotide_hmap.put('A', A_content);
        nucleotide_hmap.put('T', T_content);
        nucleotide_hmap.put('C', C_content);
        nucleotide_hmap.put('G', G_content);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to give _minimal_ subset of code, which demonstrates your question.

Comment: Well, the only place where you put something in the map is the nuc_content() method. But this method is never called anywhere.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I added the keys and values in the nuc_content() method of my subclass. If I wanted to access this in the superclass, how would I call it? Would it be within the nucleotidecontent method of the superclass or elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never call the nuc_content method in the DNASequence class. To solve this, add the line `nuc_content(dna_sequence);` to the DNASequence class. The constructor should now look like this:

```
public DNASequence(String dna_sequence){
        the_sequence = dna_sequence; 
        complement_hmap.put('A', 'T');
        complement_hmap.put('T', 'A');
        complement_hmap.put('C', 'G');
        complement_hmap.put('G', 'C');
        nuc_content(dna_sequence);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I added the static part to my HashMap. However, the printing doesnt seem to work. I added the keys and values to it in my subclass, but when I printed the size using `nucleotide_hmap.size()` in my nucleotidecontent method, it says zero when it should be 4.

Comment: @B.L. What class are you printing from, and at what line?

Comment: Well I added it in this line: 
`public void nucleotidecontent(String seq1){
  System.out.println(nucleotide_hmap.size());
  for (Map.Entry<Character, String> entry : nucleotide_hmap.entrySet()){
   System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue());
  }
 }`

Comment: When do you call the method?

Comment: I call it in the controller class (called SeqAssign). I think the line is `dna_sequence.nucleotidecontent(seq1)`.
Do I have to call the nuc_content method from the subclass somewhere?

Comment: Okay, so I did that and the code printed out 4, but this was before the HashMap part executed - that part still didn't work.

Comment: I figured out your problem. You never called the nuc_content method in the DNASequence class, and so the values were never added to the HashMap. To solve this, add `nuc_content(dna_sequence);` to the constructor in the DNASequence class.

Comment: Thank you so much! @Gus Chambers

Comment: Mind accepting my answer, if it solved your problem? (;